# innerHTML not working properly. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the result but for some reason `innerHTML` is not working properly. Can anyone take a look ?

**Not working**

```
let show = document.querySelector('#show')

fetch('/fetchDataAll')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results

            let string = players.map(function (player) {

                let colorToChange = "";
                let plusMinusSign = "";
                let colorWhite = "#FFFFFF";


                if (player.scoreChange >= 0) {
                    colorToChange = "#66FF13";
                    plusMinusSign = "+";
                }
                else {
                    colorToChange = "#D0021B";
                    plusMinusSign = "";
                }

                `<p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.playerName}</p>
                <p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.teamName}</p>
                <h3 style='color:${colorToChange}'>${plusMinusSign} ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`
            })
                .join('')

            return show.innerHTML += string

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

**Working with jQuery append()**

```
let show = document.querySelector('#show')

fetch('/fetchDataAll')
    .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
    .then(function (data) {
        show.innerHTML = ''
        let players = data.result; // Get the results

        return players.map(function (player) {

            let colorToChange = "";
            let plusMinusSign = "";
            let colorWhite = "#FFFFFF";


            if (player.scoreChange >= 0) {
                colorToChange = "#66FF13";
                plusMinusSign = "+";
            }
            else {
                colorToChange = "#D0021B";
                plusMinusSign = "";
            }

            $("#show").append(`<p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.playerName}</p>
            <p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.teamName}</p>
            <h3 style='color:${colorToChange}'>${plusMinusSign} ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
        })


    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**SOLUTION with Vanilla JavaScript**

```
let show = document.querySelector('#show')

fetch('/fetchDataAll')
.then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
.then(function (data) {
    show.innerHTML = "";
    let players = data.result; // Get the results

    show.innerHTML  = players.map(player => {

        let colorToChange = "";
        let plusMinusSign = "";
        let colorWhite = "#FFFFFF";


        if (player.scoreChange >= 0) {
            colorToChange = "#66FF13";
            plusMinusSign = "+";
        }
        else {
            colorToChange = "#D0021B";
            plusMinusSign = "";
        }

        return `<p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.playerName}</p>
        <p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.teamName}</p>
        <h3 style='color:${colorToChange}'>${plusMinusSign} ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`
    }).join('')

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: I expect to append the result to the HTML

Comment: why do you have a template literal in the middle of your code? it isn't being assigned to anything, nor used in anyway

Comment: I am trying to print it.

Comment: Well if you are meaning for it to be what is created within the map you have to return it ie: `return \`your string\``

Comment: I though I did `return show.innerHTML += string`

Comment: First where are you assigning show? And also within the second then() you are assigning show.innerHTML = '', is that correct?

Comment: it was assigned as a global variable `let show = document.querySelector('#show')`

Comment: this one is correct `show.innerHTML = ''`

Comment: Are you sure? Because if you're saying that you expect your string to be appended to the HTML of show.innerHTML, then it won't display what you are expecting because you're setting innerHTML to be empty at the start. Or is the issue that innerHTML does not equal your string?

Comment: Indeed it gets cleared at the start but then i am trying to fetch data and append it to `#show`. I store all fetched data in `string` then assigned it to `show.innerHTML` that is returned at the end.

Comment: To append in javascript, use += `...innerHTML += "..."`

Comment: this is what  I am trying to do but it does not work

Comment: You are not using += in your example , but `append`. Do $("#show").innerHTML += ".<p>...."

Comment: Do not look on the WORKING example . In the one above I used `return show.innerHTML += string`

Comment: Check my answer below. It's because you're not returning anything from map so it's empty. The string that is.

Comment: I am looking now . Trying to implement for my use case.

Comment: Ah yep. The += is for statment, but you are using it in `return`. return your node of html as a string (`return string`), then use later  += when assigning.

Comment: not sure how to implement this in my case `return string`

        `show.innerHTML += string`

Comment: I've updated the example so you can see it in the context of your code

Comment: I implemented it already. I will edit it show the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which case then it looks like it's the way you are using .map() within your function. Essentially when mapping you are not returning the string being built up. Try something similar to the following to see if it helps.

```
function then(data){
  var show = document.querySelector("#show");

  show.innerHTML = '';

  let players = data.result; // Get the results

  let string = players.map(function (player) {
    let colorToChange = "";
    let plusMinusSign = "";
    let colorWhite = "#FFFFFF";

    if (player.scoreChange >= 0) {
      colorToChange = "#66FF13";
      plusMinusSign = "+";
    } else {
      colorToChange = "#D0021B";
      plusMinusSign = "";
    }

    return `<p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.playerName}</p>
            <p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.teamName}</p>
            <h3 style='color:${colorToChange}'>
              ${plusMinusSign}${player.scoreChange}%
            </h3>`;
  }).join('');

  return show.innerHTML += string
}

function getPlayers(){
  return [{
    "scoreChange": 0,
    "playerName": "Player One",
    "teamName": "Team One"
  },{
    "scoreChange": 1,
    "playerName": "Player Two",
    "teamName": "Team Two"
  },{
    "scoreChange": 3,
    "playerName": "Player Three",
    "teamName": "Team Three"
  }];
}

then({"result":getPlayers()});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orc85dmh/

Comment: That's okay no worries, glad it helped.